# Polymorhic association, and has_many :through generating wrong sql when trying to get the through association records, rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I have created a polymorphic `Tagging` association that belongs to a `Micropost` and also a `Tag`, to illustrate

**EDITED Tagging model mistake**

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :tag, inverse_of: :taggings
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
...
```

...

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :taggings, as: :taggable, inverse_of: :taggable
  has_many :microposts, through: :taggings, source: :taggable, source_type: 'Micropost'
end
```

...

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :taggings, as: :taggable, inverse_of: :taggable
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
...
```

`Micropost` , `Tagging` and `Tag` save together fine and produce

```
<Micropost id: 588, content: "<p>hi</p>", user_id: 1, created_at: "2020-04-02 10:00:34", updated_at: "2020-04-02 10:00:34", media_data: "", pics_count: nil, share_id: nil, commentable_id: nil, commentable_type: nil, gallery_id: nil>
```

...

```
<Tagging id: 8, taggable_type: "Micropost", taggable_id: 588, tag_id: 10, topic: "Travel", created_at: "2020-04-02 10:00:34", updated_at: "2020-04-02 10:00:34">
```

(this tag already existed so we didn't need to create)

```
<Tag id: 10, name: "hello", created_at: "2020-04-01 08:39:36", updated_at: "2020-04-01 08:39:36">
```

As you can see our taggable source id and type are set correctly and our `tag_id` is saved correctly.

But when trying to do `Tag.find_by_name!("hello").microposts` it returns a empty `CollectionProxy` array.

To show the sql generated,

```
tag.microposts
Micropost Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "microposts"."id" = "taggings"."taggable_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["taggable_id", 10], ["taggable_type", "Tag"], ["taggable_type", "Micropost"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

It is putting the `tag_id` in `taggable_id` which should actually be the micropost id, therefor giving empty array.

My suspicion is that as you can see in the sql generated it is showing `["taggable_type", "Tag"], ["taggable_type", "Micropost"]` where `Tag` taggable_type should not be there but i don't know how to get rid of it.

**EDIT I add for clarity the schema**

```
create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "taggable_type"
  t.bigint "taggable_id"
  t.bigint "tag_id"
  t.string "topic"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.index ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id"
  t.index ["taggable_type", "taggable_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_type_and_taggable_id"
  t.index ["topic"], name: "index_taggings_on_topic"
end

create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.index ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name"
end
```

So lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I realized I had defined in `Tag` model this

```
has_many :taggings, as: :taggable, inverse_of: :taggable
```

should be

```
has_many :taggings
```

as we are wanting the tags.taggings not tag.taggings as taggable which will now query the `tag_id` and for tag.microposts generate the correct sql

Thnx

Answer (score 1):

change the relation in Tagging

```rb
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
end
```

the model having column of other model's id, is belongs_to that model.
The ER model would be like:

```
Micropost ---------> Tagging <------------ Tag
                   :taggable_type
                   :taggable_id
                   :tag_id
```

Comment: shit wait i screwed my code up, i re-edit the `Tagging` model